# How do we separate the built files from the source while also being able to test and see Express views from the source?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm staring to build a project in node. The directory structure I've decided to use is to have all my source files under ./src, and the files I'll eventually upload to the server under ./dist. The (not quite complete) directory structure is shown below. The ./dist structure will eventually mirror ./src once it's built.

```
|-- LICENSE
|-- Procfile
|-- dist
|   `-- server.js
|-- gulpfile.js
|-- package.json
|-- scripts
|-- src
|   |-- assets
|   |   |-- fonts
|   |   `-- images
|   |-- common
|   |   |-- directives
|   |   |-- resources
|   |   `-- services
|   |       `-- authentication
|   |-- index.jade
|   |-- less
|   |-- server
|   `-- server.js
|-- test
|   `-- server.spec.js
`-- vendor
```

My question is, when I'm setting the view folders for ./src/server.js, should I set them to the files under ./dist, or ./src? I see reasons for both, but it doesn't seem like anybody would do that.

1. serving from ./dist makes the most sense for production, obviously, since this will be the only folder shipped to the production server. Right?
2. serving from ./src will allow me to test the server and its pages before building/minifying/etc. the entire thing into ./dist.

How do people separate the built files from the source while also being able to test and see Express views from the source? Is it as simple as setting views under the conditional `process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"`? Is there a more elegant solution-- to either my server app code or directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

for the view directory, I advice to put it in the src folder and just copy them with a gulp task

Comment: Looking around more, this seems to be the common approach. I wonder though, isn't there a problem with having to run the build/copy before being able to test anything?

Comment: It depends what the build tasks does, why you have a dist repository are you using some transpiller like coffee or babel? Generally just copy html or jade files take less than 1 seconde